# mysql In clause to avoid loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have to retrieve the history of a user and I have 4 tables whose data depend on each other.I can retrieve the data using loops,but I instead used the "where IN ()" clause and I implode the output of the previous query.However,if the list I provide to "where IN()" is empty it return an error.Is it that IN() cannot be empty?

Comment: What have your tried... right now you are leaving us guessing and scratching our heads....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When imploding an array for the IN clause, i do one of two things

1: Check if you even need to run the query at all

```
if(!empty($some_array)) {
    //run mysql query
}
else {
   // if you need to do something if the array is empty, such as error or set some defaults, do it here
}
```

2: A value in the array initiliser which is not ever in the database (for example, if im selecting based on a auto incrememnt id, i use zero as a default array value to stop any issues with empty data sets, as zero will never be in my id column).

```
$some_array = array(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an empty value to the start, such as `IN (0,your values here)`

Comment: +1 Just make sure the fake value used _will never occur in the real data_